# Как обернуть цикл в условие? Лимит цикла

Tags: python, pyautogui, count

Вроде бы простая задача но я буквально не вижу синтетических ошибок так как совсем юнец. Буду рад комментариям заранее.

Вот простой цикл:

- 1.Берет список из текст файла.
  2.Выбирает один элемент из списка.
  3.Вставляет его в другой текст файл.

```
import pyautogui

f = open(r"C:\Users\Alphabets\Desktop\Python local\readme.txt", "r")
        
def func():
    pyautogui.click(1362, 476)
    for i in f:
        pyautogui.hotkey('enter')
        i = i.split(":")[0]        
        pyautogui.typewrite(i)
        pyautogui.PAUSE = .5

func()
```

Нужно обернуть в условие которое остановит исполнение цикла. Например после 5 итераций.

Так выдает 3 итерации первого элемента.
Необходимо 3 раза по порядку списка

```
import pyautogui

f = open(r"C:\Users\Alphabets\Desktop\Python local\readme.txt", "r")
        
def func():
    pyautogui.click(1362, 476)
    count = 0
    for i in f:
        while count < 3:
            pyautogui.hotkey('enter')
            i = i.split(":")[0]        
            pyautogui.typewrite(i)
            pyautogui.PAUSE = .5
            count += 1
func()
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать `enumerate`:

```
import pyautogui

f = open(r"C:\Users\Alphabets\Desktop\Python local\readme.txt", "r")

def func():
    pyautogui.click(1362, 476)
    for n, i in enumerate(f, 1):
        pyautogui.hotkey('enter')
        i = i.split(":")[0]        
        pyautogui.typewrite(i)
        pyautogui.PAUSE = .5
        if n == 5:
            break

func()
```